# AJAX data posted with jQuery contains quotes?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have been struggling with this for a while now, somehow JQuery is escaping the quotes on the text, that's ok, but when the string is shown to the user I want to be shown as the user wrote it, here is the simplified code:

### Test.PHP

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="testform" action="testoutput.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="data" id="data" />
        <input type="submit" />
    </form>

    <div name="output" id="output"><b>The Output</b></div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#testform').submit(function () {
        $data = $('#data').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'testoutput.php', 
            type: 'POST',
            data: "data=" + $data,
            success: function(response) {
              $('#output').html(response); 
            }
          });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

### testoutput.php

```
<?php
    $data = $_POST['data'];

    echo $data;
?>
```

Now, if in the form I write something like **"Ok"** the output will show **\"Ok\"** I had trying things like:

```
$data = escape($('#data').val());
```

in order to avoid the quotes even being there when the request is sent, but somehow the ajax request is also escaping that, am I missing something here?

I don't mind the escaping, but why is JQuery doing this, why is this encode/decode/escape stuff happening in the background?

Comment: Do you have [magic_quotes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) turned on?

Comment: *jQuery is **not** adding those quotes*. Look at the data *actually sent* to the server in a developer tool.

Comment: @AndrewR it turned out that in the production server they have...

Comment: Thanks @pst, I really thought jQuery was to blame

Comment: @im8bit Magic quotes is deprecated in 5.3 and removed from 5.4. If you plan on upgrading your PHP version, you may need to look at modifying your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`stripslashes` is probably the tool you need, but make sure you TEST for magic quotes being on before removing slashes.

If you ever transport your code to a new system that has a different config, then you'll have a heck of a time tracking it down..

```
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    // Do your stripslashes here.
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-magic-quotes-gpc.php

Comment: Thanks @Jeremy, this was it, and thanks a lot for the extra tip, i'm definitely including that in the code.

Answer (score 1):

I think its the server adding those slashes (via [magic quotes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php)) to remove them use [`stripslashes`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php)

```
echo stripslashes($data);
```

or better yet have it turned off

as @jeremyjstarcher suggest check to see magic quotes is on before strip slashes

```
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    $data = stripslashes($data);
}
```

Comment: See my post.  I strongly recommend checking for magic quotes being on in case code is moved or settings changed.  Otherwise you risk corrupting valid data at a later point.

Comment: Yea, turned off is better -- but there may be other code out there that depends on it.  Not to mention I figure a lot of people don't have access to to turn it off.  *Mutter-mutter* Like me, on one of the sites I run.  My standard library runs everything through a recursive de-magicquote at start up.